# Conditional report parameters in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report which requests a parameter value for `customerNo`. The report should return all values by default.

Once the user provides a single `customerNo` value, then it should display the specified record only.

I've found solutions for Multiple selection, but couldn't find for single text box entry.
Thanks guys..

Comment: source of the dataset? dataset database?

Comment: MSSql database, Using Visual Studio Reporting System.

Comment: Do you want it to be a multi select checkbox? or just a single text box ?

Comment: Just single textbox Bhupesh, As i said i found solution for multiple selection, but not for single textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Report Design

Change the report parameter to allow `NULL`:

[image: SSRS Parameter Allow NULL]

Modify the `WHERE` clause of the data set to check `NULL` parameter value:

[image: SSRS Dataset]

### Report Execution

When the report is run, users can check `NULL` for all rows:

[image: SSRS Report All Rows]

Or rows matching a specific value:

[image: SSRS Report Parameter Value]